# How many steps does it take to visit every cell of a 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following problem I can't figure out on my own.

There is a 2D array with 8x8 dimensions. A dog is randomly put within this dimension. The dog is not allowed to walk out of the dimension, if it does those steps are not counted. Every step the dog takes to another square is counted. Each simulation should calculate the number of overall steps it took for the dog to visit all squares of the 8x8 dimension at least once.

How do I know if all 64 squares got stepped at least once to stop the simulation and print the steps?

```
int [] [] onSquare = new int [8][8];
int counter = 0;

int x = rnd.nextInt(8); // random position for the dog 0-7
int y = rnd.nextInt(8);


for (int i = 0; i < onSquare.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < onSquare.length; j++) {
        onSquare [i] [j] = -1;    // dog is on no square in beginning
    }
while (onSquare[i][j] == -1) {
    int dog = rnd.nextInt(4)+1;    // random movement from dog

    if (dog == 1) {
      x++; // x,y show position of the dog
      counter++; // number of steps
      if (onSquare[i][j] == onSquare[x][y]) { <---- This gives me errors when checking if x,y lies within i,j
         onSquare[i][j] = 1; // stepped on square
      }

    }
    if (dog == 2) {
      x--;
      counter++;
      onSquare[i][j] = 1;
    }
    if (dog == 3) {
      y++;
      counter++;
      onSquare[i][j] = 1;
    }
    if (dog == 4) {
      y--;
      counter++;
      onSquare[i][j] = 1;
    }
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > onSquare.length || y > onSquare.length) {
      counter++;
      onSquare[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of "dimension"? why is it initialized in columns? you will need to add bounds checking. is this homework? it seems like this is a starting point they gave you and you have to fill in the missing pieces or something?

Comment: @dave-cousineau dimension represents the number of squares that are available to step on

Comment: well, not sure, but it sounds like you don't need the `dimension` array. the `onSquare` array is good enough to track where the dog has been, x and y are good enough to track where the dog is now, and 8 is good enough to track the bounds of the area.

Comment: *"How many steps does it take to visit every cell of a 2d array?"* Between 63 and ∞. --- No matter the starting position, there is always a path that visits every 64 squares without stepping on an already-visited square, so 63 steps to visit them all. --- Since no rules were listed preventing stepping on an already-visited square, or that an optimal path should be followed, the dog can walk around randomly, as dogs often seems to do, and hence may never visit all 64 squares, which is what *"least once"* would tend to indicate could happen. --- So why is your code not using `Random`?

Comment: @Andreas The dog moves randomly and can go to each field several times. Each step is counted. I want to find out how many steps in total it takes for him to get on all squares if he moves in a random direction. I have random values asigned with int dog = rnd.nextInt(4)+1;

Comment: @Peon Sorry, I didn't see that `rnd` in there, because it's not declared anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a steps counter to keep track of movement, for each movement, increment its value.

instead of using boolean array, use int array for tracking cells traversed.

```
int [] [] onSquare = new int [8] [8];
```

initialize all the cell to have -1 , indicating no dog movement to the cell yet.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 8; i++ )
    for(int j = 0; j < 8 ; j++ )
        onSquare[i][j]=-1;
```

when dog enters it, assign its value to 1 , indicating presence of dog

when dog exits, assign its value to 0, indicating absence of dog

once all cell have non-negative value, stop the simulation and display the value of steps counter!!

**Edit: since you are struggling to solve , here is the complete code:**

```
    /**
 * This simulation assumes dog movement is discrete relative to grid cells
 * i.e. its either in one of these cells at a time, overlapping two cells in not allowed!!
 * **/
public class DogMovementSimulation 
{
    int onBoard[][] = null;
    int dogPosX = 0;
    int dogPosY = 0;
    int dogPrevPosX = 0;
    int dogPrevPosY = 0;

    int directionOfMovement = 0;
    int stepsCount = 0;

    DogMovementSimulation()
    {
        onBoard = new int[8][8];
        //initialize each position in onBoard to -1 ,implying dog has not been placed yet, not even once!!
        for( int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++ )
        {
            for( int j = 0 ; j < 8 ; j++ )
            {
                onBoard[i][j] = -1;//implying dog has not been placed yet, not even once!!
            }
        }

        //place dog in random cell
        dogPosX = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*7);//generating random number between 0 and 7, since index is from 0 to 7 as there are 8 cell!!
        dogPosY = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*7);
        //assigning 1 to onBoard at index dogPosX,dogPosY to indicate dog has been placed there
        onBoard[dogPosX][dogPosY] = 1;
    }

    /*this function returns false if any cell has -1,else true
     * cause when all cells have been traversed , each cell have non negative value,either 0 or 1 
     *  */
    public boolean areAllCellsTraversed()
    {
        boolean result = true;

        for( int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++ )
        {
            for( int j = 0 ; j < 8 ; j++ )
            {
                if( onBoard[i][j] == -1 )//implying this cell not traversed yet,i.e dog not placed in this cell yet!!
                {
                    result = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void simulate()
    {
        //loop while all cells have been not traversed
        while( !areAllCellsTraversed() )
        {
            directionOfMovement = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*3);//generating random number between 0 and 3
            switch( directionOfMovement )
            {
            case 0://move left-to-right
                dogPosX += 1;
                if( dogPosX >= 7 ) dogPosX = 0; //since largest array index is 1 less than its size, we compare with 7 instead of 8                 
                break;

            case 1://move right-to-left
                dogPosX -= 1;
                if( dogPosX <= 0 ) dogPosX = 7;                 
                break;

            case 2://move top-to-bottom
                dogPosY += 1;
                if( dogPosY >= 7 ) dogPosY = 0;                 
                break;

            case 3://move bottom-to-top
                dogPosY -= 1;
                if( dogPosY <= 0 ) dogPosY = 7;                 
                break;
            }

            //assign 0 to previous position, meaning dog is no longer there
            onBoard[dogPrevPosX][dogPrevPosY] = 0;
            //assign 1 to new position , meaning dog is here
            onBoard[dogPosX][dogPosY] = 1;

            stepsCount++;
            dogPrevPosX = dogPosX;
            dogPrevPosY = dogPosY;                  
        }   
        //once all cells have been traversed , print result!!
        printSteps();
    }   

    /*prints the total number of step taken to traverse all cells*/
    public void printSteps()
    {
        System.out.println("Total steps taken by dog to traverse all cell = "+stepsCount);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DogMovementSimulation dms = new DogMovementSimulation();
        dms.simulate();     
    }
}
```

Comment: So, I need an if statement that whenever its outside the grid assign onSquare[i][j] = 0?

Comment: whenever the dog is outside the cell at i,j assign onSquare[i][j]=0 , indicating its not in that cell.

Comment: I can't figure out how this works/explain. It has no effect on the steps at all wenn I have something like if x < 0 (outside the cell) { onSquare[i][j]=0 }

Comment: I think you need to explain a bit more, before I can help you. First of, is there a single dog or multiple?? cause I see you have used, int dog = rnd.nextInt(4)+1;

Comment: what do you mean when you say "The dog is not allowed to walk out of the dimension, if it does those steps are not counted." Is the area of movement , greater than the total grid size?? and is the dog movement between grid cells[i.e from one cell to another cell at a time] or continuous[i.e it moves in small increments , increment being less than the size of each cell]??

Comment: There is one dog. The movement of the dog is continuous taking small random increments until it covered all squares of the dimension. When the dog takes random steps and the position is outside the dimension it goes directly back inside[i.e if x < 0 do x++ so  dog moves to the right resulting that hes inside dimension again. Take so many steps until dog stepped on every square once (steps are counted multiple times).

Comment: you mean , dog is moving in anyone of the 4 directions, left-to-right, right-to-left, top-to-bottom or bottom-to-top at any moment, onces its out of the grid, it comes back to the grid. Also, you change the direction of movement randomly every time loop continues. You want to end the animation once every cell in the gird(dimension 8x8) has been traversed at least once. am I correct??

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am looking for. What is the key to this problem what am I missing? I want to understand this, as I just got into arrays.

Comment: the above code in question is incomplete, but from part you have posted, I see you are incrementing counter in only one direction and each time the dog moves. what you should do , is check if the dog has moved from one cell to another, if it transitions to new cell say, onSquare[i+1][j], then make onSquare[i+1][j]=1 and old cell onSquare[i][j]=0; don't mix increment of movement of dog and counter , increment counter only when dog has left one cell and entered another!!

Comment: Whenever I add 1 to i onSquare[i+1][j], the index is out of bound. I edited my new code in the start post. As, it is right now this shows me 64 steps.

Comment: one error I spotted is, you have missed one } before while. Also, I don't see a code to update value of i and j based on dog position!!

Comment: How do I accomplish to update the value of i and j based on dog position? Putting x and y inside onSquare [] [] gives me another error of index is out of bound. This problem makes no sense to me!

Comment: you should test if x,y lies int he bounds of onSquare[i][j]. lets say, each square[i.e cell] on your grid is 20x20 pixels, then cell0(i.e onSquare[0][0] ) has bounds as new Rectangle(0,0,20,20) , cell1(i.e. onSquare[1][0]) has bounds new Rectangle(20,0,20,20) and so on...., now ,if your increment of x and y is 5, after you increase x or y, test which square it lies in using if(onSquare[i][j].contains(x,y) ) {onSquare[i][j] = 1; onSquare[i-1][j]=0;} for left-to-right movement. if you still don't get it, post your entire code. Let me see what have you done or is your code algorithm correctl!!

Comment: I updated my code and how I want to compare if onSquare[x][y] is within onSquare[i][j]

Comment: you are getting error cause you are doing it the wrong way!! onSquare[i][j] is meant to keep track of cell traversed.

Comment: if (onSquare[i][j] == onSquare[x][y]) <---- This gives me errors when checking if x,y lies within i,j, is not the way to test if x,y within the bounds of onSquare[i][j]

Comment: x,y is the position of dog, but i,j are indices of onSquare 2D array, but you are using x,y as indices of array onSquare in above code, which is wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203845/discussion-between-gulshan-chaurasia-and-peon).

Answer (score 0):

Going to write this as a series of suggestions, otherwise I'd feel like I'm basically writing an assignment for you.

It sounds like you should get rid of `dimension`, since it isn't doing anything useful.

You should store the value `8` in a variable.

```
int size = 8;
```

It sounds like you're trying to both check when all squares have been visited, but also check how many steps were taken, including revisiting old squares. For this you will require two counters, not one.

```
int steps = 0;
int visited = 0;
```

You need bounds checking to make sure `x` and `y` don't go out of bounds.

```
if (dog == 1 && x < size - 1) {
   x += 1;
   steps += 1;
```

You need to check whether the dog has visited this location before. If he hasn't been here before, then increment the counter.

```
   if (!onSquare[x][y]) {
      onSquare[x][y] = true;
      visited += 1;
   }
```

You need to stop when you've visited every location.

```
while (visited < size * size) {
```

Comment: I understand I need to flip it from false to true once it stepped on the available square but I always get that the Index is out of bound which I do not understand since x and y (position) is within the size.

Comment: @Peon you need `x < size - 1` when adding 1, and `x > 0` when subtracting 1. same for `y`.

Comment: I can't figure out my mistake... My output is that it takes 64 steps to visit all 64 squares, well if the movement is in a random direction as specified the amount of steps should be much higher right ?

Comment: @Peon updated, since it sounds like you want both the total number of steps, but also to stop after the last cell has been visited. the way I had it written at first, you would count only the new cells, so it would always be 64. I've turned `counter` into `steps` and `visited`.